# alarm on screen change

Tags: image, screen, autohotkey

I have to use a software which list my clients processes. I need a sound alert program if something change on 50x10 pixel region. I try to write a program on autohotkey but i can't succeed in. Anybody have this program?

Comment: Please provide some feedback on the proposed solution and if the answer was helpful, "Accept" the answer. Thank you!

Comment: Please provide some feedback on the proposed solutions and if one of the answers was helpful, then please "Accept" that answer by clicking on the white check-mark to turn it green. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example that you can use.

```
^Launch_Media:: ; Make a reference screenshot with NirSoft NIRCMD by pressing Ctrl+Media or any other program...
run, "C:\Program Files\1 My Programs\nircmd.exe" savescreenshot "c:\Temp\Screenshot.bmp" 33 40 17 20 ; Location of "Save As" Icon in SciTE4AutoHotKey Editor
Return

Launch_Media:: ; Launch this test manually with Media Button
CoordMode Pixel  ; Interprets the coordinates below as relative to the screen rather than the active window.
ImageSearch, FoundX, FoundY, 0, 0, 200, 200, C:\Temp\Screenshot.bmp ; search for image in area staring at 0,0 to 200,200
if ErrorLevel = 2
    MsgBox Could not conduct the search.
else if ErrorLevel = 1
    MsgBox Image could not be found on the screen.
else
    SoundBeep, 1000, 1000
    MsgBox The Image was found at %FoundX% %FoundY%.
    ClickX:=FoundX + 5 ; Move the mouse click away from the edge of the icon
    ClickY:=FoundY + 5 ; Move the mouse click away from the edge of the icon
    Click, %ClickX%, %ClickY% ; Click on the Save As icon.
Return
```

When we know more about what you want to test (I think that an area of 50x10 might be too small), and what you want to do in case the area has changed, we might be able to help you with a more suited script.

In this example I used [NirSoft](http://www.nirsoft.net/)'s nircmd.exe, but you can create a reference image by other means as well. If You only need an audible alarm,  you can comment all the other commands under `if, then, else` out with <kbd>;</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check this post from 2 years ago in the AutoHotKey community?

http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/56219-fast-screen-change-check-using-histograms/

The above script might be a little overwhelming, but you can also create a screenshot of a fixed area and do an image comparison in AutoHotKey as others have done before you.